# MySQL - SQLite - Converting is spitting out SET error

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I am trying to convert the following sql into sqlite via sqlite3.exe but it keeps giving me this error:

```
Error: near line 1: near "SET": syntax error
```

I'm not entirely sure what this means or why. Here is my sql script:

```
SET SQL_MODE = 'NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO',
time_zone = '+00:00';

CREATE TABLE `px` (
  `x` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `y` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `colour` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `time` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `px`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `px`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

I'm sure i'm overlooking a simple syntax error. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: have you deleted the line and see if the conversion works.

Comment: Where did you get the impression that `sqlite3` would convert a MySQL script? Any links to the documentation on that?

Comment: [Right Here](https://www.guru99.com/sqlite-database.html#4:~:text=sqlite3%20SQLiteTutorialsDB.db%20%3C%20SQLiteTutorialsDB.sql) That link should scroll right to the line in chrome. @stickybit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can 't just run a MySQL script in SQLite. These are two different databases, whose syntax differ.

In SQLite, a relatively close syntax to the MySQL script would be:

```
CREATE TABLE `px` (
    `x` integer NOT NULL,
    `y` integer NOT NULL,
    `colour` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    `time` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    `id` integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
);
```

Comment: I'm aware. And thanks for still answering. I'm pretty sure the sqlite tools exe has this command biult in for conversion though, and that's where i'm getting the syntax error. `C:\sql\> sqlite3 database.db < db.sql`

Comment: @IsaacLloyd sqlite does not have a set statement, and sql mode is mysql specific configuration option. You cannot run a mysql script in sqlite and expect it to work. This answer is accurate.

Comment: @Shadow thanks for the clarification. Sql is very different from anything i've ever played with before. Wish me luck! And thanks :)